# How to create a simple REST service in mirth connect

Tags: rest, http, service, mirth

I've just entered in mirth connect world,I need to know ,how to create a simple rest api service in mirth,generate a  url, the vendor hits to send the data to our mirth api.

Comment: You can just use the http listener........is this something that will be internal to your organization or will the API be used by people outside of your network?

Answer (score 2):

You can use HTTP Listener in Source tab (image below) and set up custom headers and authentication.

[image]